# While (Iterator2.hasNext()) related issue as my data is not populating in rows but cell wise

Tags: java

My data is not populating in excel row wise but cell wise in Excel.

Please check my expectation.

```
        Column 0   Column 1   Column 2
Row 0               APP1       APP2
Row 1     Computer          
Row 2     Mobile
Row 3     Tablet
```

My current code providing result below

```
        Column 0   Column 1   Column 2
Row 0               APP1       APP2
Row 1     Computer          
Row 2     
Row 3
```

Please check my current code

```
Iterator<String> tempIterator2= devkeys.iterator();

Integer cellnumd = 0;
Integer rownum2 = 1;
XSSFRow row2 = sheet.getRow(rownum2);

if (row2 == null) {
  sheet.createRow(rownum2);
  continue;
}
Cell cell2 = row2.getCell(cellnumd);
while (tempIterator2.hasNext()) {
  String tempdev = (String) tempIterator2.next();
  if (( cell2 != null) || ( cell2 == null)){
    cell2 = row2.createCell(cellnumd);
    cell2.setCellValue(tempdev);
    rownum2++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You created just one row.
Later, you iterate over `tempIterator2` and increase the `rownum`, but ignore the incremented value.

On top of that:
`if (( cell2 != null) || ( cell2 == null))` is confusing.
This is equal to `if (true)` - cell2 can either be null or not null. There is no other option.

You may also consider for loop:

```
for (String tempdev : devkeys)
```

over using an iterator explicitly.
The output will be identical (iterator is used by the for loop), but this is considered more readable.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am fetching the data from Map.
 for (String appkey : appkeys) {
              XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(rownum);

```
          m1= (Map) M2.get(appkey);
          devkeys = m1.keySet();
          for (String devkey : devkeys) {

                    m0 = (Map) m1.get(devkey);
                 browkeys = m0.keySet();
              for (String browkey : browkeys) {
                          System.out.println("Total Count = " + m0.get(browkey) + " " + m1.get(devkey) +  " " + browkey + " " + devkey + " " + appkey );
                           browsercnt = (Integer) m0.get(browkey);

                          }
            }
```

}